# NLTK perplexity error

Tags: python, nltk

I got this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/shengrong/Desktop/bigram", line 55, in <module>
        bg = bigram(file)
      File "C:/Users/shengrong/Desktop/bigram", line 43, in bigram
        return tt1.perplexity(my_bigrams)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\model\ngram.py", line 217, in perplexity
        return pow(2.0, self.entropy(text))
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\model\ngram.py", line 205, in entropy
        e += self.logprob(token, context)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\model\ngram.py", line 151, in logprob
        return -log(self.prob(word, context), 2)
    ValueError: math domain error




import os,csv,nltk
from nltk.model.ngram import NgramModel
from nltk.probability import LidstoneProbDist

fout = open("/Users/shengrong/Documents/personal/WN1.data.csv", "w")

outfilehandle = csv.writer(fout,
                           delimiter=",",
                           quotechar='"',
                           quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)  


localrow = []
localrow.append("File name")
localrow.append("Perplexity for unigram")
localrow.append("Perplexity for bigram")
localrow.append("Perplexity for trigram")
outfilehandle.writerow(localrow)

def bigram(file):
   file_object = open(file)
   ln=file_object.read()

   words = nltk.word_tokenize(ln)
   my_bigrams = nltk.bigrams(words)
   my_trigrams = nltk.trigrams(words)



   tt1=NgramModel(2, my_bigrams, estimator = None)


   return tt1.perplexity(my_bigrams)    




#set the path of the folder 
os.chdir("/Users/shengrong/Documents/A") 
s = os.getcwd() 
#search files in the folder 
files = os.listdir(s) 

for file in files:
    bg = bigram(file)
    localrow= []
    localrow.append(file)
    localrow.append(bg)

    outfilehandle.writerow(localrow)

fout.close()
```

How to fix this problem? Without using loop to read a folder, my code is working well.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is a Math domain error. Since it works without the loop, it may be that one or more of the files contains some data that cannot be processed by the Math package.

Please confirm that all files in your folder contains data in the correct format and with expected values.

Comment: they are all txt files. For some files, it is working well; However, for others, the math domain error occurs.